# get the collection size on client without subscribing it to the whole collection

Tags: pagination, meteor

I'm trying to setup pagination for my app. Got most things working except getting the number of pages. The main point of pagination is not to send the full collection to the client until he requests it, so I limit the subscription serverside. Thus, collection `.count()` is always limited to the page size on the client.

I tried things like that, but it doesnt work:

```
Meteor.publish 'count', -> Items.find().count()
```

Comment: Can you share how you did pagination without transferring everything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically you want a client only collection which is fed by a custom publish function.
See http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_publish the second example on how to do that.
With this method you can generate data without any corresponding server side collection.

Something along those lines:

```
Meteor.publish("counts", function() {
  var self = this,
      count = 0,
      uuid = Meteor.uuid();

  var handle = TargetCollection.find({}).observe(function() {
    added: function() {
      // Document added, increase count and push it down the pipe.
      count++;
      self.set("counts", uuid, {count: count});
      self.flush();
    },
    removed: function() {
      // Document removed, decrease count and push it down the pipe.
      count--;
      self.set("counts", uuid, {count: count});
      self.flush();
    }
  }
  // Observe only returns after the initial added callbacks have
  // run.  Now mark the subscription as ready.
  self.complete();
  self.flush();

  // stop observing the cursor when client unsubs
  self.onStop(function () {
    handle.stop();
  });
}
```